# Toggle dropdown menu on li but prevent toggle clicking on ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On mobile im using javascript to toggle the dropdown.
When clicking on a list item the dropdown should get visible and on a second click toggle back.

The problem: if i like to use a search bar inside my dropdown menu the dropdown get toggled back to unvisible clicking inside search bar.

Jquery:

```
$('.has-dropdown-two').on('click', function() {

            $(this).toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');  

  });
```

First of all i tryed to make an if clause like:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('nav-dropdown-two') ) ..
```

Not working... then i checked console.log(this) and it looks like clicking on ul it has the same output like when clicking on li.

**I made a very simple preview:**

```js
$('.has-dropdown-two').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

   
      $(this).toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible'); 
 
  });
```

```css
.has-dropdown-two > .menu-link { display: inline-block; }

.has-dropdown-two.is-active > .nav-dropdown-two {
    display: block;
}

.nav-dropdown-two {
  display: none;
      position: absolute;

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <li class="menu-item has-dropdown-two"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="menu-link stopnewline">Search</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown-two menu">
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form action="">
                      <input type="text"  name="search">
                      <button type="submit">search</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>                
       </ul>
        </li>
```

**Edit according lumio's solution:**

```
 $('.has-dropdown-two').on('click', function(event) {
    if ( event.target.tagName === 'A' || event.target.tagName === 'I' ) {
            $(this).toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
  }else{
    return;  
  }
  });
```

Comment: Some clarification for your problem. Clicking on the UL will indeed trigger the click of the LI since the LI encapsulates the UL. Everything inside the LI is considered as triggering the click event of the LI. At the moment I don't have time to look for a solution if it's later on still not solved I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed as mrdeadsven mentioned. The events bubble up. That means if a click event happens on the child, it also happens on the parent. Unless it gets prevented.

You could either set the click handler on the `<a>` tag or you could check, what was actually clicked on by passing the event argument to the event handler function.

```js
$('.has-dropdown-two').on('click', function( event ) {
  // Check the tagName of clicked target element
  const tagName = event.target.tagName;
  if ( tagName === 'INPUT' || tagName === 'button' ) {
    return;
  }
  
  var $this = $(this);

  $(this).toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
});
```

```css
.has-dropdown-two>.menu-link {
  display: inline-block;
}

.has-dropdown-two.is-active>.nav-dropdown-two {
  display: block;
}

.nav-dropdown-two {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item has-dropdown-two"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-link stopnewline">Search</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown-two menu">
      <div class="search-container">
        <form action="">
          <input type="text" name="search">
          <button type="submit">search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could do the above example very easily without using jQuery.

---

The other solution would be to check if the `<a>` tag caused the event to fire. This might be even the better solution as it works for nested sub menus as well.

```js
const subMenuToggle = ( event ) => {
  // Only watch clicks on .toggle-switch
  if ( !event.target.classList.contains( 'toggle-switch' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Prevent the actual click on the link
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Toggle .is-active on parent <li> element
  const parent = event.target.parentNode;
  const className = 'is-active';
  parent.classList.toggle( className );
  
  // Only open the next direct ul
  parent.querySelectorAll( ':scope > ul' ).forEach( ( element ) =>
    element.classList.toggle( className )
  );
};

// Get all ul.navigation on the page
document
  .querySelectorAll( '.navigation' )
  .forEach( ( element ) => {
    element.addEventListener( 'click', subMenuToggle );
  } );
```

```css
.nav-dropdown-two {
  display: none;
}

.nav-dropdown-two.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- added .navigation for later -->
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="menu-item has-dropdown-two">
    <!-- added the .toggle-switch for the event listener -->
    <a href="#" class="toggle-switch">Search</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown-two menu">
      <li>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="search">
            <button type="submit">search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-switch">more</a>
        <ul class="nav-dropdown-two">
          <li>Sub menu</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think its the most efficient solution, thanks.   Im editing my post to share my result.

Comment: This is a good solution except for one thing(which is kind of a drag but it is worst case scenario). What if there is a nested LI? For example inside the form they start a new LI and you wouldn't want the nested LI to trigger the click event. This scenario will not be solved with your tag system. Even now if you take away the FORM and they push the button the search tab will again be invisible because the button is not in the tagName INPUT and so it will trigger the click event.

Comment: @mrdeadsven .. right I forgot about the button. Updated my answer and added an example where the event listener is only running if it was caused by the anchor tag.

Comment: @mrdeadsven      exact the problem i run into for my second part navigation. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @lumio          i wasnt successful on the second part navigation i mentioned above. Mobile only: i have a LI element wich toggles an UL element, inside i got 2 LI elements where each can toggle a second UL element. I tried only with 'event.target.classList.toggle('is-active');' but then the LI inside the LI element has 2 listener wich toggle the is-active class. As result it get added and removed instantly.

Comment: The second version works by adding a class to the toggle switch, the `<a>` tag. You need to add the `toggle-switch` class to it to work

Comment: I updated the code, so it shows an example with a multi-layer navigation

Comment: I had to make a few more changes because my code is a bit more different, but now its working. I finaly understood more or less how your snippet works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lumio         Is there any way to add the listener to the main element only witouth using event.stopPropagation() ? For example i have something like: <li><a> <i class="fa fa"></i></a>  <ul></ul> </li>. Now im like to toggle the UL element only if i click on the LI element but not trigger anything clicking inside the UL element. One problem is that A and I should be able to trigger.

Comment: Where is the problem having it on the `<a class="toggle-switch">` tag? You can style that tag however you like and it will only trigger when clicked on the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mrdeadsven commented, it's due to the [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation).

You can turn it off by attaching another listener to your form and call `event.stopPropagation()` in it.

```
$('form').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a good way to go. Although it works adding additional event listeners just to stop propagation is bad practice as it clutters the event loops and in the end becomes rather confusing to debug.